# Qt on Mac: add an existing UI file without rebuilding the whole project

Tags: c++, xcode, qt

I have a Qt project in XCode on Mac. I want to add an existing .UI file to it. When I do that by listing in the .pri file, the XCode project itself is rebuilt by qmake, and all my post-qmake settings are lost. Is there a way to insert a UI file without listing in the .pri? It's doable in a very straightforward way on Visual Studio...

Comment: what post-qmake settings? Are you editing makefiles by hand? If so, look into either an automated way of doing that, or find a way to integrate the settings in your .pro and .pri files...

Comment: No, I'm editing the project in Xcode by hand. Like adding some bundle resources, changing compiler settings, etc. All Mac-specific stuff.

Comment: I've learned long time ago, that Qt qmake doesn't work good enough with Xcode. I always make Xcode project by hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two custom steps in the target - both call make over files in the project bundle (xcodeproj). The first one invokes qmake. The second invokes the Qt proprocessors - uic, moc. So the answer is - comment out or delete the first step, modify the makefile of the second one by hand. Add generated files (once they're generated at least once) to the project as necessary.